My Spring application doesen't load CSS after upgrading from Spring 2.2 to 2.7
After i updated my Spring project from 2.2 to 2.7, my css are no longer loaded for some strange reason. No particular changes have been made to the project and i'm reading that nothing should change in the CSS aspect but i don't understand why the CSS are no longer loaded.
Maybe they changed the folder structure? But i didn't find anything about that.
My folders are structured in this way:


could you please also share your application.properties or application.yaml files?

Check these,
Ensure your CSS files are located in src/main/resources/static or a recognized location like /public, /resources.
Clear the cache or use incognito mode to avoid cached versions causing issues.
Ensure your security configuration allows access to static resources:

These are all things already checked, as you can see from the image the paths are the ones indicated by you. Furthermore, with Spring version 2.2 everything worked
